# Why spring data mongo not returning the field having time?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a document in my collection like

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e3aaa7cdadc161d9c3e8014"),
        "carrierType" : "AIR",
        "carrierCode" : "TK",
        "flightNo" : "2134",
        "depLocationCode" : "DEL",
        "arrLocationCode" : "LHR",
        "depCountryCode" : "DELHI",
        "arrCountryCode" : "LONDON",
        "scheduledDepDateTime" : ISODate("2020-02-05T00:30:00Z")

}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e3aaacddadc161d9c3e8015"),
        "carrierType" : "AIR",
        "carrierCode" : "TK",
        "flightNo" : "2021",
        "depLocationCode" : "DEL",
        "arrLocationCode" : "LHR",
        "depCountryCode" : "DELHI",
        "arrCountryCode" : "LONDON",
        "scheduledDepDateTime" : ISODate("2020-02-05T00:00:00Z")
}
```

I am putting criteria like

```
   Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria = criteria.and("carrierCode").is("TK");
     String from = "2020-02-05";
      String to = "2020-02-05";
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date toDate = dateFormat.parse(to);
                    Date fromDate = dateFormat.parse(from);
                    criteria = criteria.and("scheduledDepDateTime").gte(fromDate).lte(toDate);
```

But i am getting document only the field which have time `00` not both the document. I have two documents with that date but in response getting only one. I have tried so many things but not succeed. I want to compare only the date and ignore the time. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *from* and *to* dates must be the lowest time and the highest time for that date, respectively; this will cover all the hours of the day.

For using the same field ("scheduledDepDateTime") with the *$and* operator you must use the `Criteria`'s `andOperator` not the `and` (see [AND Queries With Multiple Expressions Specifying the Same Field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-field)).

The updated code:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria = criteria.and("carrierCode").is("TK");

String from = "2020-02-05 00:00:00";
String to = "2020-02-05 23:59:59";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s");
Date toDate = dateFormat.parse(to);
Date fromDate = dateFormat.parse(from);

criteria = criteria.andOperator(where("scheduledDepDateTime").gte(fromDate), where("scheduledDepDateTime").lte(toDate)));

// Query qry = new Query(criteria);
// List<SomeClassName> result = mongoTemplate.find(qry, SomeClassName.class, "collection_name");
```

Comment: Thanks @Prasad, but i am getting only date in request like String from = "2020-02-05" so when I do DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s"); it is giving me format exception because time is not there in request. Also how do i add time in my toDate field like 2020-02-05 23:59:59 .Because i have only date in my request.

Comment: The request from/to date data (which is of string type) can be appended with the "  00:00:00" and " 23:59:59" respectively within the program. Then, parse those strings to get the needed `fromDate` and `toDate` which you can use with the query.

Answer (score 0):

The ISODate in mongod is stored as an epoch timestamp with millisecond resolution.

`dateFormat.parse` is likely returning ISODate("2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z"), which would be stored in the db as `1580860800000`.

This effectively means your query is `{scheduledDepDateTime:{$gte: 1580860800000, $lte: 1580860800000}}`, so the only possible value that could satisfy the filter is ISODate("2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z").

To get all documents with that date, you might try making your `toDate` be the following day, and use `$lt` instead of `$lte`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @prasad **todate must be the lowest time and the highest time for that date** I have to set time in todate field to 23:23:59 like this and it works.

```
 public static Date convertToDate(final Date date) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
```